# "this" in underscore is undefined after compiling with browserify and debowerify

Tags: gulp, underscore.js, browserify, babeljs

So first.. I have next gulp task:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    browserify('./src/js/main.js')
        .bundle()
        .on('error', onError)
        .pipe( source('main.js') )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(path.build.js) );
});
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      ["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }],
      "debowerify"
    ]
  },
}
```

I am importing Backbone in main.js (or only underscore... it doesn't matter)

```
import Backbone from 'backbone';
```

And in console I am getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined

I checked code and found that in underscore sources at start of library `root` is undefined

```
 // Establish the root object, `window` in the browser, or `exports` on the server.
  var root = this;

  // Save the previous value of the `_` variable.
  var previousUnderscore = root._;
```

I think the problem is that debowerify or babelfy is wrapping code in some function. But also if I use node modules without debowerify all works fine. But I want to use bower.

So how to fix this problem?

Comment: Same error over a year apart, this time due to using webpack - Any chance you resolved this issue in a prettier way?

Answer (score 1):

To any future visitors to this question,

this is similar to [Underscore gives error when bundling with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301399/underscore-gives-error-when-bundling-with-webpack)

The gist of the issue is that babel is probably running the underscore.js code, since underscore.js uses `this`, and in es6 `this` is undefined when outside of a function, naturally `this._` fails.

In code I've fixed the issue by ensuring that babel does not run on node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same error arose when using just browserify with underscore. I've workarounded issue by switching from underscore to lodash. They are in general (surely not fully) compatible, but at the worst I'd rather copy some missing function from underscore sources than live with its deisolated load approach.